# $state.go with reload doesn't update other components

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am working on an angularjs app and I have the following issue. One of my directives is the top nav bar with details about the user. Like login, register, logout etc.

```
function UserNavDirective() {
    var ddo = {
        templateUrl: 'app/views/common/usernav.html',
        scope: {

        },
        controller: UserNavDirectiveController,
        controllerAs: 'usernav',
        bindToController: true
    };

    return ddo;
}

UserNavDirectiveController.$inject = ['AuthFactoryService', '$cookieStore'];

function UserNavDirectiveController(AuthFactoryService, $cookieStore) {
    var usernav = this;

    usernav.loggedIn = AuthFactoryService.checkIfLoggedIn();
    usernav.username = $cookieStore.get('username');
    usernav.logout = AuthFactoryService.logout();


}
```

Then I have a service for the logout and login. I will post the logout which is the smaller one.

```
  authService.logout = function() {

       $cookieStore.remove('token');
       $state.go('home', {}, { reload: true });

  }
```

I tried everything I found in Google and Stackoverflow, but still it keeps the usernav controler with the old data until I manually refresh the page.

Comment: what data in particular remains?

Comment: I have a couple of ng-show and hide for authenticated users. After the login or logout, I use the $state.go from the auto controller to redirect to home state. But the usernav scope has the previous data.

Comment: on logout, you could either clear ALL clear all properties in the usernav one by one or make usernav an empty object

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove token from header and then cookies so try this

```
$http.defaults.headers.remove = ['Authorization'];
 $cookieStore.remove('globals');
```